# How do I join two tables and return the values from the first that aren't in the second table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, the first containing the id and employee_name, and the second containing the employee_id (same as id) and some other columns. How do I join the first table with the second so that I can output all the employee ID's (and the rest of the columns) in the first table that don't appear in the second? The query I've gotten to is this:

```
select employee_id
from data2 left join data1 on data2.employee_id = data1.id
where employee_id is NULL
```

This outputs the correct number of rows, but there are no values in them. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the filter to be where data1.id is NULL ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: `select * from data1 except select * from data2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tables are flipped in your SQL. Based on your narrative, the SQL should be:

```
select data1.*
from data1
left join data2 on data2.employee_id = data1.id
where data2.employee_id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use join, you can simply use 'not in' clause

```
select id
from table1
where id not in (select employee_id from table2)
```

Let me know, if it works.

Comment: Joining is better, or NOT EXISTS. More intuitive NULL handling and sometimes better index usage. It is virtually always best to avoid not in and use NOT EXISTS. Especially in this case where we know employee_id can be NULL.

Comment: 'Not Exists' will only result in TRUE or FALSE and will not give the list of employee id from the second table. To avoid null cases, you can add another clause using AND. I guess its better to use 'Not exists' than Join since you will have less data set to work on. 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists

Comment: "'Not Exists' will only result in TRUE or FALSE" - That isn't correct.

Comment: @Error_2646 I have not seen 'Exists' Operator returning some rows or dataset. Would like to see it, if you could attach in any Blog that says that. Thanks. This would be insightful.

Comment: EXISTS is very useful. I can't find a good blog, but here's just an example of usage for this case https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-exists/ One of the main benefits is that you can do more complex logic easily in the condition for example WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.field1 = CASE WHEN blahblahInTable2 END AND Table2.Field2 IN ('A','B','C') ....  ) In the simplest case you get simpler NULL handling and better index coverage, in more complex cases it can really simplify the query over using IN/NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the records from `data1` whose values of `employee_id` do not exist in the column `id` in `data2`.

The way the current query is structured, you are asking for `employee_id ... where employee_id is NULL` so that will only return null records. Instead, make a query of `data1` like this:

`select * from data1 where employee_id not in
(select id from data2)`

This uses the subquery to find a list of `id` values in `data2` and then only returns records from `data1` whose `employee_id` does not exist in that list.